# Como manipular vários inputs com mesmo name em Java?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, input

Como faço para manipular no back-end utilizando Java vários `input`'s com o mesmo `name`?

Por exemplo:

```html
    <input type='text' name='telefone' ><br>
    <input type='text' name='telefone' ><br>
    <input type='text' name='telefone' ><br>
    <input type='text' name='telefone' >
```

Tentei receber no parâmetro do método como um `array(String[] telefone)` mas não deu certo. Tentei colocar também os `[]` no `name` mas também não deu certo.

Ps: *Estou utilizando o SpringMVC.*

Comment: Marcos, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Dê uma olhada em ["Como fazer uma boa pergunta?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e ["MVCE"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Poste a parte relevante do formulário (incluindo action, etc), bem como os pedaços relevantes do seu backend (controller, etc). 
Em geral resolvemos esse tipo de problema usando uma `List` como `@ModelAttribute` e nomes numerados na view (e.g, `telefone[0]`, `telefone[1]`, etc), porém é difícil te dar um conselho sem conhecer o código em maiores detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vou levar em consideração que você está enviando esses dados para o backend usando form-data, se for isso, você pode receber um List telefones no seu controllers, e o spring vai dar bind para você, porem entretanto seus inputs devem seguir uma notação similar a de um array, algo como:

```html
    <input type='text' name='telefone[0]' ><br>
    <input type='text' name='telefone[1]' ><br>
    <input type='text' name='telefone[2]' ><br>
    <input type='text' name='telefone[3]' >
```

No seu controller:

```java
    public void salvaTelefones(List<String> telefones) {
      //faz algo.
    }
```